# How to echo a specific value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, for-loop

Hei 
i got a quick question.
I want to upload an XML File and echo it through a for loop.

This is my XML:

```
<notfall>
<mitarbeiter>
<vorname>Thomas</vorname>
<name>Meier</name>
<handynummer>01701427475</handynummer>
<gruppen>EDV</gruppen>
</mitarbeiter>
<mitarbeiter>
<vorname>Max</vorname>
<name>Mustermann</name>
<handynummer>012441212415</handynummer>
<gruppen>EDV, Immo</gruppen>
</mitarbeiter>
</notfall>
```

This is php code:

```
 <?php 
$notfall=simplexml_load_file ("notfall.xml");
echo $notfall->mitarbeiter[0]->handynummer;
$countnotfall = count($notfall);
for($i=0;$i<$countnotfall;$i++){
  echo $notfall ->mitarbeiter[2]->vorname;
}
?>
```

I want to echo every name of my array without hard coding every line.
Can you tell me how i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just loop over all of the `<mitarbeiter>` and output the data of each item...

```
$notfall=simplexml_load_file ("notfall.xml");
foreach ( $notfall->mitarbeiter as $mitarbeiter )   {
    echo $mitarbeiter->handynummer.PHP_EOL;
    echo $mitarbeiter->vorname.PHP_EOL;
}
```